# why do i get an error when trying to use vuefire plugin?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuefire

it tried to import the Vuefirestore plugin from Vuefire and register it with vue.use, but when compiled it says: 'Vue' is not defined no-undef for some reason.

```
import { firestorePlugin } from 'vuefire'
Vue.use(firestorePlugin)
```

Does somebody have an idea why?

Comment: where is `Vue` define ?, add `import Vue from 'vue'` at first

Answer (score 0):

you first need to `import Vue from 'vue'`

Comment: thanks! but now it says "export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

Comment: are you using vue 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm using vue 3